# Validate No of message processed in AWS SQS with the no of files i get from those messages in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-glue

I have a lambda which is processing each message i get in SQS queue and stores a file in any of the two folders within s3 for each message but now end of the day i want to validate the no of message i received in SQS with no of files i get in S3 and if it does not match notify me.

I already have a dead letter queue and related notification process linked to SQS.

I am thinking to have a glue job which will pull the received message from its count metrics and take no of files or object from each folder in s3 combine it and validate it if its does-not match send notification email. Is it Possible.? and how.?

Comment: can you share what have you tried so far?

Comment: i am trying using glue job in mind but i am open for other suggestion.

Comment: You could probably try a custom CloudWatch metric that is essentially S3 GetRequest - SQS ReceiveRequest. Then create an alarm on it when it's not 0.

Comment: will Custom metrics helps in.? as i have to run it once a day and i only need the count to be validated.